# Set Default Content Type Using CSOM Not Working

Tags: content-type, csom

Please look at my code below and let me know where I'm going wrong. This code is not working to reorder a list's content type order using CSOM.

```
List aeList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Events and Announcements Demo1");
ContentTypeCollection oContentTypes = aeList.ContentTypes;       
Folder rootFolder = aeList.RootFolder;
ContentType[] orderedContentTypes = new ContentType[1];

foreach (ContentType oContentType in oContentTypes)
{
    if (oContentType.Name == "Events and Announcements")
    {
        orderedContentTypes[0] = oContentType.Id;
        rootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = orderedContentTypes[0]; /*I'm receiving Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId>'   error here*/

        rootFolder.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Events and Announcements content type is set to default");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give this a try:

```
List aeList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Events and Announcements Demo1");
var currentCtOrder = aeList.ContentTypes;
context.Load(currentCtOrder, coll => coll.Include(
                        ct => ct.Name,
                        ct => ct.Id));
context.ExecuteQuery();

IList<ContentTypeId> reverseOrder = (from ct in currentCtOrder where ct.Name.Equals("Events and Announcements", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) select ct.Id).ToList();
aeList.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = reverseOrder;
aeList.RootFolder.Update();
aeList.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you Nadeem.